# react native map not rendering nested array components

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use this Code to render a nested array of images inside the array of objects but it doesn't work it just left an empty space according to CSS added

```
            {
                POSTDATA.map((data => 
                {
                    data.productImages && data.productImages.length > 0 &&
                        data.productImages.map((image) => 
                        <Image
                            key={image}
                            style={styles.wrap}
                            resizeMode="stretch"
                            source={{ uri: image }}
                             />
                        )
                    }
                ))
            }
```

this is the function which is then rendered in the main exported function.

```
wrap: {
    width: width,
    height: height * 0.50,
},
```

this is the css used in the code where the width and height are from Dimensions components decided through 'window'

```
const POSTDATA =[
    {
        key: 1,
        name: 'You Shine',
        rating: '3.5',
        gender: 'female',
        likes: 300,
        productImages:[

            "../../assets/image/ethnicDress.jpg",
      
            "../../assets/image/ethnicDress2.jpg",
        
            "../../assets/image/ethnicdress3.jpg",
        
            "../../assets/image/ethnicdress4.jpg"
        
        ],
    productTitle: "ladies trendy Evening gouns with a traditional touch",
    productDescription: "This is really a new Trend. Where the western gouns are made with a slight touch of Indian Tradition",
    commentsNumber: 235,
    productComments: [
        {
            key: 1,
            userName: "_user_name_",
            comment:"this is really an amazing product and can make you stand out"
        },
        {
            key: 2,
            userName:"_user_name_2",
            comment:"I Think this is not a genuine price for such a product it must be somewhat cheaper"
        }
    ]

}
]
```